# ionic 2 sidemenu - pass nav from app.ts to menu component

Tags: angular, ionic2

I need to implement a logic same as given in the below link:
[ionic 2 sidemenu - navCtrl inside a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192947/ionic-2-sidemenu-navctrl-inside-a-component)

I have ion-nav in app.ts & within the app.html there is another custom component(menu.ts). From inside the menu.ts, I want to navigate/set another component as root

I am getting error
**Cannot read property 'setRoot' of undefined**

How can I pass nav from app.ts to the menu component?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to pages like this:

## app.ts

```
this.nav.setRoot(page.component, nav);
```

and afterwards read them with:

## page.ts

```
constructor(public params: NavParams) {
    this.nav= params.get('nav');
}
```

But this shouldn't be necessary when you want to call "setRoot" I do it like this:

## page.ts

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
} 

....

navigateToPage() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page);
}
```

Comment: I have ion-nav in app.ts & within the app.html there is another custom component(menu.ts). From inside the menu.ts, I want to navigate/set another component as root.